# If someone is just a passenger in a boat or a ship

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I understand that we commonly use the verb "row" to driving boats. Also some other verbs like "propel" and "paddle". What I understand that those verbs give the meaning of controlling the boat. What if someone is just a passenger who doesn't drive or skipper?

Comment: Then they are riding on the boat, just like they could be riding on a bus. Or they're taking a boat ride, just like they could  take a bus ride. They are not rowing or paddling the boat if they are just sitting there.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use the verb **[take](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take%20the%20boat%2Cride%20the%20boat%2Cride%20the%20ferry%2Ctake%20the%20ferry&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20the%20boat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cride%20the%20boat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cride%20the%20ferry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20the%20ferry%3B%2Cc0)** to mean "be a passenger on".

> They took the boat across the ocean.
>
> They took the ferry across the channel.
>
> She takes the train to work.